# Is it possible to connect a NOT gate (74hc04) to connect two separate circuits in parallel?

Tags: digital-logic

Say I am low on the number of IC, can I use the same not gate for two different connections in parallel in a breadboard? Will there be any interference like short circuits or unexpected behavior if I do this?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean connecting to outputs from another ICs into a single input in a NOT gate?

Comment: Kind of, yes. I am making a 7 segment display, and I don't have anymore NOT gates. So I was thinking of connecting the rest of the required connections to pins (of the IC) I have used before.

Comment: can you try to post a schematic? Ctrl + M should open the editor

Comment: ![alt text](https://scontent-sin1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/v/t1.0-9/12994505_1112223248842115_3413975059092303280_n.jpg?oh=0ec4ef92dc780e6733d02d8308da7d38&oe=57B2CBB2 "Logo Title Text 1")

Comment: What does "connecting the rest of the required connections to pins I have used before" mean? Which pins? You obviously can't just connect things to random pins, your circuit won't work that way.

Answer (score 8):

The X, Y, and Z lines all seem to be connected to multiple NOT gates.  Instead, you only really need three NOT gates, and derive three lines \$\small \overline{\text{X}}\$, \$\small \overline{\text{Y}}\$, and \$\small \overline{\text{Z}}\$ and route those as necessary to the inputs of the next level.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about connecting one output to two inputs, that's fine. I don't remember the limit ("fan-out") but it's well above 2.

If you are talking about connecting two output to one input, no don't do it! If one output is driving high and one low, you're essentially making a short circuit through them and may well destroy them!

The only time you can connect multiple outputs together are if they are open-collector (aka open-drain) outputs which only pull low and instead of driving high, go high-Z (open circuit). This is used in things like I2C buses.

Comment: Fan-out limits for CMOS parts like the 74HC family depends on operating frequency; at low frequencies, though, it's high enough to be effectively unlimited.

Comment: Fan out of 10 LS-TTL loads [datasheet](http://www.solarbotics.net/library/datasheets/MM74HC04.pdf)